# How to make return do the same as print in python string

Tags: python

```
b = 'abbaab'
count = 0
width = 2
for k in range(0, len(b), width):
    print b[k:k + width]
```

gives me

```
 ab
 ba
 ab
```

but I need to use return instead of print. I don't know how to store each line into something, the things I tried said index out of range.

Comment: store them in a list and return the list. http://www.openbookproject.net/pybiblio/gasp/course/A-lists.html

Comment: `return` wants a function. You should consider writing a function to let you use `return`.

Comment: *the things I tried said index out of range*. Post the things you tried and the error you got

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work , Solution in Python 2.7.6:

```
def print_list(b):
    count = 0
    width = 2
    for k in range(0, len(b), width):
        yield b[k:k + width]
b = 'abbaab'
l = list(print_list(b))
for i in l:
    print i
```

**Output**:

```
ab
ba
ab
```

Here I am using `yield` statement to instead of `return` to return the every line element and trying to convert all into `list` and every element in list represent each line Or else it is not necessary to convert it into `list` you can use this:

```
 for i in print_list(b):
    print i
```

If you want to use `return` then Solution :

```
def print_list(b):
count = 0
width = 2
ans = []
for k in range(0, len(b), width):
    ans.append(b[k:k + width])
return ans

b = 'abbaab'
for i in print_list(b):
    print i
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: or more simply:  `for i in print_list(b):`  No need to turn a generator into a list

Comment: @ joel goldstick thanks for advice.. I will make changes . I am used to making everything into `list`.

Answer (score 0):

`print` and `return` are very different.

Print is a function that will just print out something to the screen. return is a command that basically tells what value a function should return. For example:

```
def func1():
    print 1

def func2()
    return 2
```

if you do

```
first_result = func1()
second_result = func2()
```

you will see that

```
first_result = None
second_result = 2
```

but if you run them

```
func1()
func2()
```

you'll see that only `1` will be printed to the screen. In order to print the return of a function, you have to explictly ask for it

```
print func2()
```

With that in mind, and heading to your problem, you can store your things and return that to the function, and just then ask for python to print everything out

```
def func3():
    b = 'abbaab'
    count = 0
    width = 2
    things = []
    for k in range(0, len(b), width):
        things.append(b[k:k + width])
    return things

print func3()
```

Of course in this csae, you will print all values at once. In order to print each line separately, iterate the result and print each element

```
value_returned = func3()
for element in value_returned:
    print element
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `return` to be same as `print`, `return` switches context from `callee` to `caller` function, with some value or none.
Whereas `print` is used to send some output to `console`

They both cannot be same.

In your case, assuming that you want to write this code snippet as a function and return values that are being printed, it should be done as follows:

```
def foo():
    b = 'abbaab'
    stack = []
    count = 0
    width = 2
    for k in range(0, len(b), width):
        stack.append(b[k:k + width]);
    return stack;
```